# Regex match for color response in linux

Tags: regex, linux

I have a colored response from one of my server. I have a regular expression which is NOT working on that server. If I go to any other server, the response comes in black and it matches fine. Also I took the response and tried out other regular expression matching web sites and t worked smooth.

Any suggestion how to match the specific regular expression OR how we can change the color setting for the text . The specific server is "CentOS release 5.5 (Final)"

Regards,
Udaya

Comment: Please give an example, show your regular expression and what a "colored response" is in your context. (HTML? Terminal output via SSH?)

Comment: It is a terminal output via SSH .

Comment: And the image can be seen here (as I dont have privilege to post a pic here)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwI_HENAPomLXBkZHZLMC11U0E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colors are contained in the output in the form of [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). You can remove the color codes by replacing all occurrences of

```
\033\[[0-9;]+m
```

Or, since your output seems to be from `ls`, simply use its `--color=never` option.